# Either You Or It

Tags: riddle, computer-science

On the left, I am "you".
On the right, I am "it".
On the forward, I am either "you" or "it".
What am I?

Subtle hint:

> I myself is always on the left.

Moderate hint:

> There are two kinds of "it".

Decisive hint:

> And

Comment: is that a variable?

Comment: @rsonx Yes, kind of.

Comment: That is an if-else comparison. right?

Comment: @rsonx Not in the language.

Comment: What does forwardly means? This might be the branch prediction.

Comment: @rsonx On the second thought, an if-else comparison is needed anyway.

Comment: @rsonx "Forwardly" not related to branch prediction.

Comment: I think I figured it out. See my updated solution.

Comment: rot13(Zvtug or fgq::sbejneq_vgrengbe naq fgq::erirefr_vgrengbe, ohg gurer'f nyfb n [onmvyyvba](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) bgure xvaqf bs vgrengbef, fb V'z guvaxvat abg (nppbeqvat gb uvag 2))

Comment: @Avi rot13(Abg na vgrengbe.)

Comment: Darn! I answered this question before I started learning C++!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, second attempt. You are a:

> **reference**

*On the left, I am "you".*

> **Lvalue references** refer to a live object, hence "you".

*On the right, I am "it".*

> **Rvalue references** refer to a temporary object, hence "it".

*On the forward, I am either "you" or "it".*

> **Forwarding references** can either be lvalue references or rvalue references.

Hints:

Hint 1:

> *I myself is always on the left.*
>  References themselves are always lvalues.

Hint 2:

> *There are two kinds of "it".*
>  Rvalues are further classified as prvalues or xvalues.

Hint 3:

> *And*
>  References are declared like `type&` (lvalue reference), and `type&&` (rvalue reference).

Comment: Gah! Inaccurate explanation. rot13(Gur nafjre vf "ersrerapr", abg gur nqqerff-bs bcrengbe.)

Comment: @DannyuNDos rot13(Gung jnf gur nafjre. Gur bayl ernfba "bcrengbe" vf gurer va cneragurfrf vf gung `&` nyfb unccraf gb unir gur anzr "ersrerapr bcrengbe", fb vg'f grpuavpnyyl nyfb ba gur yrsg/evtug)

Comment: rot13(V zrna V bayl vagraqrq gur ersrerapr glcr.)

Comment: @DannyuNDos Ah, fair enough

Comment: Since your answer was the most accurate, I gave you the bounty. Your answer has been edited to the intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> a `boolean` taking a value through the `|=` operator (in C++/Java)

As an example:

> ```
>  boolean you = ...;
>  boolean it = ...;
>  you |= it; // you, depending on the values of you and it, is either you or it
> ```

*On the left, I am "you".*

> **you** |= it;

*On the right, I am "it".*

> you |= **it**;

*Forwardly, I am either "you" or "it".*

> In C++/Java, the |= operator returns the value that was assigned, in this case `you | it`,  i.e., **you or it**

Comment: But what exactly am "I"? If "I am `you`", then "On the right I am `it`" doesn't quite make sense, because on the right `it` is simply another variable. If "I am `boolean`", then I'd say it makes equal sense to say "I am `int`": just change all the `boolean` to `int`, and `|=` means bitwise or.

Comment: @WhatsUp You're right, I'm not sure what it is then

Comment: rot13(Lbh tbg gur evtug ynathntr, ohg fbeel, gung'f vapbeerpg.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> `std::conditional`?

Still trying to work out the hints.

Extra:

> You said that C++ was the correct language in the comments under another answer.

<sub>[note: this answer has been through many changes, please see the edit history to reveal all the incorrect guesses that I made]</sub>

Comment: @DannyuNDos rot13(Vf vg gur greanel bcrengbe?)

Comment: This looks very much like the correct answer, especially with the comment "On the second thought, an if-else comparison is needed anyway." But for me it's a bit strange to say "on the left, I am `you`" while `you` is effectively "in the middle"...

Comment: @WhatsUp Yeah, still trying to work that out. It may be that `you` is the condition.

Comment: Sorry, not the correct answer either. rot13(Gur ynathntr va punetr vf P++, abg Wnin.)

Comment: @DannyuNDos Taking another shot. This good?

Comment: Gah! You interpreted my comment correctly, but the answer is something completely different.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Does the answer contain text from the decisive hint?

Comment: Err... No......

Comment: Why so many punctuation marks?

Comment: Because there is a lower limit on the comment length.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a Boolean set by a conditional statement?

Example:

> `int a = 7;
>
>  bool you = false; // set the boolean value to false
>
>  you = (a > 5); // “you” will be equal either to itself (still) or to the result of the comparison (the “it”)`

Comment: rot13(Fbeel, gung'f vapbeerpg.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are

> a string (in an if-else or other conditional statement)

First of all,

> "you" and "it" are in quotes

On the left, I am "you".

> `if(stringName === "you") { something happens }`

On the right, I am "it".

> `else if(stringName === "it") { something else happens }`

On the forward, I am either "you" or "it".

> without the if-else statement (or any other conditional statement) the string could either be "you" or "it" and the action will still take place.

Hint

> Declared as "you":
>  `String stringName = "you";`

Comment: Sadly, not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you?

> A varying iterator

On the left, I am "you".
On the right, I am "it".
On the forward, I am either "you" or "it".

> A forward iterator between two fixed iterators begin() and end() is either pointing to an element in the range (which we can refer to as being of the type "you" as it is pointing to an object and calling it out -- imagine the pointer as someone literally pointing their finger and yelling "You!", "You!", "You!") or points to nothing (more specifically points to something outside the range i.e. points to nothing in particular) in which case it is simply an iterator (it). When performing forward iteration (from left to right), the varying iterator goes: you-you-...-you-it

Comment: Sadly, not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Condition

On the left, I am "you".

> A variable declared by you.

On the right, I am "it".

> A value that has something to do with the variable

On the forward, I am either "you" or "it".

> you dont need to state condition when you use a function

Comment: Sadly, not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you an

> Iterator statement like
>
> ```
>  this->it = *it;
> ```
>
> Let's analyse this solution. On the left, I am "you". On the left of the arrow this references the current class (or you). On the right, I am "it". On the right of the arrow, it is the iterator variable. On the forward, I am either "you" or "it". By forward I am guessing you mean the forward iterator (or perhaps the forward arrow). Hint 1: I myself is always on the left. this is always on the left. Hint 2: There are two kinds of "it". One is it the other is *it. Hint 3: And. Not sure about this one...
>  Or perhaps it is
>
> ```
> this = this->it;
> ```